# Cast function firebird

Tags: sql, casting, firebird, firebird-3.0

How can I convert 0 as float?
`Cast( 0 as float )` return singe not float?

for example I have a table X with F1 field - float 
When use

```
Select (cast(0 as float)) as F1 from X
```

return error

> Expecting float actual: Singe.

Comment: I assume you mean "single" instead of "Singe", and btw, what gives this error, because performing the cast itself does not produce any error.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast to `double precision`. The `float` datatype in Firebird is actually a SQL `real` (or 32 bit single precision).